# asp.net (Visual studio 2013)

Tags: asp.net

I am writing a `Web API` on Visual Studio 2013(in `C#`). While building the code Visual Studio shows no error and build succeeds. But when i try to hit a controller using my browser keeping visual studio in debug mode.The control does not goes to the debug point at controller instead it throws an exception a point which is unrelated to the flow.Saying:

> Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.4.4.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

even though this assembly is there in reference of this project.

Comment: You have to put more details, the error is clearly and the problem is with MySql.Data assembly.

Comment: When you compile and then try to debug IIS Express has to spin up the service.  In the process of that it tries to make various connections it needs in order to run the project.  Connecting to the database is a part of that and it looks like that is where you are failing.  My hunch is your connection string is wrong.